# SQlite opens a connection and creates a table but does not INSERT INTO the table

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I am building an app to store infomation using SQlite. It Opens a connection and creates a table but dose not INSERT INTO the table.

Please what am I doing wrong

From step 1 to step 3 works but I cannot see the table in the devtool

```
(function() {

  const dummyDb = {};
  dummyDb.webdb = {};

  dummyDb.webdb.db = null;

  dummyDb.webdb.open = function() {
    let dbSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB
    dummyDb.webdb.db = openDatabase(
      "dummy Database",
      "1",
      "dummyDb Data Collection Database",
      dbSize
    );
    console.log(`#1`);
  };


  //##### Step 2. Creating a table #####
  dummyDb.webdb.createTable = function() {
    let db = dummyDb.webdb.db;
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
        "dummyDb_tbl(dummy_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, dummy_created_by TEXT, dummy_date_on DATETIME)", []
      );
      db.addDummy("Dummy text has been added bla bla bla");

    });
    console.log(`#2)`);
  };

  //###### Step 3. Adding data to a table ######
  dummyDb.webdb.addDummy = function(dummyText) {
    let db = dummyDb.webdb.db;
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
      let addedOn = new Date();

      tx.executeSql(
        "INSERT INTO dummyDb_tbl(dummy_created_by, dummyd_date_on) VALUES (?,?)", [dummyText, addedOn]
      );
    });
    console.log(`#3`);
  };


  dummyDb.webdb.open();
  dummyDb.webdb.createTable();

})();
```

I want to to INSERT data into the addDummy() function

Answer (score 0):

You define the function in the `dummyDb.webdb` object with the following line.

```
dummyDb.webdb.addDummy = function(dummyText){...};
```

Then you try to call it on the db object

```
let db = dummyDb.webdb.db;
db.addDummy("Dummy text has been added bla bla bla");
```

This should give an error like "function is not defined" because the db object doesn't have a function called addDummy.

Try to use

```
dummyDb.webdb.addDummy("Dummy text has been added bla bla bla")
```